# How handle and correlate the dynamic value asf cognito data in Jmeter

Tags: jmeter

Iam not able to find the asfcognitodata value in the response body, as it is showing in the request but it is not showing in the response body so iam not able to correlate that value and iam stopping.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v3k60.png)

I have tried to correlate the asfcognito data value but that value is not present in the response body

Answer (score 0):

Looking at [Cognito documentation](https://aws.amazon.com/cognito/faqs/):

> Amazon Cognito lets you easily add user sign-up and authentication to your mobile and web apps. Amazon Cognito also enables you to authenticate users through an external identity provider and provides temporary security credentials to access your app’s backend resources in AWS or any service behind Amazon API Gateway. Amazon Cognito works with external identity providers that support SAML or OpenID Connect, social identity providers (such as Facebook, Twitter, Amazon) and you can also integrate your own identity provider.

So is you "need help" you need to be more specific: i.e. which identity provider, which protocol, what exact dynamic parameter you cannot handle, etc.

If you're looking for generic help:

- [How to Load Test SAML SSO Secured Websites with JMeter](https://dzone.com/articles/how-to-load-test-saml-sso-secured-websites-with-jm)
- [OpenID Connect - How to Load Test with JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/openid-connect-jmeter)

In general it's a matter of [correlation](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.html#correlate-start) so it's sufficient to identify the dynamic parameters, extract them from the previous response and replace recorded values with the variables references.

You might also need to generate a signature, the [algorithm](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/sig-v4-authenticating-requests.html) is also publicly available